# Replacing forward slash with hyphen in date VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched all over and normally find my answer, however this one is peculiar. I have to format a date for a program such that it doesn't have forward slashes in the date to write to a file path. I am able to get the **look** in the cell to appear as if it's using hyphens, but the **value** in the formula bar still shows it with backslashes.

For instance, today's date could be typed into cell A1 as *"10/18/2017"* and it would appear in the cell it's typed as *"10-18-2017"*, but in the formula bar and when I get the value of the that cell it's still *10/18/2017*.
I'm extracting the value like: `Range("A1").value`

Below is the code that I'm using to try to change the actual value of the cell.

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
```

This did exactly what I mention above. Tricks the user into thinking they solved the problem, but not really. Then I thought well let's just replace the `/` character...

```
Range("A1").value = Replace(Range("A1").value, "/", "-")
```

Still no dice and not anything I can find on the interwebs. Sorry if this has been answered, I searched and searched, even within stack

Comment: If you are simply doing this to create a file name when saving, why don't you just set the format when you create the file name itself? `FileName = Format(MyRng, "MM-DD-YYYY")`

Comment: Thanks @K.Davis, but @stenci had the approach I was looking for. Without going into too much detail, I needed the format to be with hyphens in Excel as I was opening that file with a Mitutoyo program to extract data within. When I used `Range("A1").value` it would still give me the date with `/` rather than `-` which was a problem. Within that program I was building a file path using this variable assigned to `Range("A1").value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Range("A1").Text` instead of `Range("A1").Value` you get whatever formatting was applied to the cell.

Comment: This is what helped my problem, thank you. Never thought of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The value shown in the formula bar has nothing to do with how you're formatting the date in Excel.

It's a system-wide setting that you'll have to modify by going to Control Panel > Region and Language.

Edit:

And, as K.Davis said in your comment, you can simply use `Format(rng, "mm-dd-yyyy")` to name the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the string in the code

```
    Sub SaveIt()
    Dim s As String
    s = Format(Range("A1"), "mm-dd-yy")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\" & s & ".xlsm", _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```